# Where and when to pronounce O as A and when to pronounce it as O?

Tags: фонетика

Is there any rule of thumb of where and when to pronounce O (in Ukrainian words) as /a/ and when to pronounce it as /o/?

Is it supposed to be like in Russian language?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Ukrainian you simply pronounce `о` as /ɔ/ and `а` as /ɑ/ (they are almost never intermixed).

It's true that in unstressed position vowels can be pronounced less clear than in stressed position. The most prominent example is `е` /ɛ/ and `и` /ɪ/, which both can approach [e] (so, when recovering written form from the oral form, you sometimes are unsure whether you should write `е` or `и` in unstressed position). Other vowels also may somewhat "deviate" when in unstressed position (e.g. `а` /ɑ/ → [ɐ], `о` /ɔ/ → [o], `у` /u/ → [ʊ]). But `а` /ɑ/ and `о` /ɔ/ "deviate" much less than in Russian, from a practical point of view you can think that `а` /ɑ/ and `о` /ɔ/ don't "deviate" at all.

Some English soruces:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_phonology#Vowels

Comment: I would lile to add, that *o* is mostly can be like *u*, but not *a* in those cases. Especially when we speak about West and North Ukrainian.

Comment: The sound of “о”, when followed by stressed “у”, can also deviate somewhat towards /u/ in words like “кожу́х”. Still, a learner would do well pronouncing everything as written.